# Pandas group by aggregation for non numeric data

Tags: pandas

my sample `df` looks like this:

```
sid    score   cat_type
101      70      na
102      56      PNP
101      65      BAW
103      88      SAO  
103      50      na  
102      42      VVG  
105      79      SAE  
....

df_groupby = df.groupby(['sid']).agg(
    score_max = ('score','max'),
    cat_type_first_row = ('cat_type', '?')
)
```

with the `group by`, I want to get the first row value of `cat_type` that is not `na` and assign it to `cat_type_first_row`

my final `df` should look like this:

```
sid    score_max   cat_type_first_row
101       70              BAW
102       56              PNP
103       88              SAO  
105       79              SAE  
....
```

Could you please assist me in solving this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replace na to `NaN` and do `first`

```
df_groupby = df.replace('na',np.nan).groupby(['sid']).agg(
    score_max = ('score','max'),
    cat_type_first_row = ('cat_type', 'first')
)
df_groupby
     score_max cat_type_first_row
sid                              
101         70                BAW
102         56                PNP
103         88                SAO
105         79                SAE
```

Comment: thanks for composing the answer. does this first remove all data which has row `na/nan`? if that is the case then it should not happen since only after I `group by`, I can pick the first value of that group which is not na/nan

Comment: @floss this dose not remove it ,. first willl select the first not nan value

Comment: quick clarification: when we do df.replace('na',np.nan), does that not replace `NaN` value first from the DF and then perform `groupby` with the DF with no `NaN`?

Comment: @floss so you have NaN and na in your df ?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it :)

Comment: @floss it will treat the na and NaN the same after replace , and will not output both of them in first function

Comment: I did that but it does not remove the NaN value. its asif (after seeing the first few row)... having `replace('na',np.nan)` or not having provides the same response.

Comment: @floss you should add one more df.replace({'na':np.nan,'NaN':np.nan})

Comment: quick clarification: I want to confirm that `df.replace({'na':np.nan,'NaN':np.nan})` does not remove `NA` or `NaN` values form the `df` first and then perform `group by but it will only remove `NA` or `NaN` values after doing the group by and then selecting the first value. is this correct?

Comment: @floss YES CORRECT

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to drop any row, you could use:

```
(df.merge((df.dropna(subset=['cat_type'])
             .groupby('sid')['cat_type']
             .first()
             .rename('cat_type_first_row')
          ), on='sid')
)
```

output:

```
   sid  score cat_type cat_type_first_row
0  101     70      NaN                BAW
1  101     65      BAW                BAW
2  102     56      PNP                PNP
3  102     42      VVG                PNP
4  103     88      SAO                SAO
5  103     50      NaN                SAO
6  105     79      SAE                SAE
```

Comment: I should not drop the data before doing group by. once I do the group by and then on that group, I can drop NA/NAN and then select the first non-nan or non-na value

Comment: @floss it does not drop data, the `dropna` if only for selecting the row in 'cat_type'

Answer (score 2):

You can define a function that takes as input the grouped pandas series. I've tested this code and got your desired output (added rows for cases when all cat_type values are np.nan for a group):

```
df = {
    'sid': [101, 102, 101, 103, 103, 102, 105, 106, 106],
    'score': [70, 56, 65, 88, 50, 42, 79, 0, 0],
    'cat_type': [np.nan, 'PNP', 'BAW', 'SAO', np.nan, 'VVG', 'SAE', np.nan, np.nan]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
display(df)

def get_cat_type_first_row(series):
    series_nona = series.dropna()
    if len(series_nona) == 0:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return series.dropna().iloc[0]

df_groupby = df.groupby(['sid']).agg(
    score_max = ('score','max'),
    cat_type_first_row = ('cat_type', get_cat_type_first_row)
)
df_groupby
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: what `series` are we passing to the function?

Comment: Each `series` that is grouped by pandas `groupby`. For example, all values of cat_type where sid == 101, and so on.

Comment: I am getting this `single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`

Comment: That must be for sids where all cat_type values are `na`. Try checking the length of `series.dropna()` and add a conditional for when the length is 0, then return the value you want.

Comment: since `get_cat_type_first_row` is a function... why is there no parameter passed? eg: get_cat_type_first_row(series)

Comment: Got the error you mentioned by adding a new sid with corresponding cat_type values that are all `np.nan`. Added an edited function in my answer that works for these cases.

Comment: It is being called within the pandas `groupby` function. In this code I am telling pandas to call `get_cat_type_first_row` and use it as an aggregation operation. It will then use the resulting grouped series as the argument.

Comment: I think because of my data size, it is taking a long time to process - still waiting

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to work on the solution. It looks like it works but the code is still running. I upvoted but marked another answer as correct by BENY.

Comment: You're welcome! :) This solution is definitely not optimized. I just had an itch to replace your '?' aggregation operator. ;) You can read more about user defined aggregation functions here:

https://medium.com/escaletechblog/writing-custom-aggregation-functions-with-pandas-96f5268a8596